# Is no FileIOPermission on paid webhosting normal?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, file-permissions

I'm currently buying webhosting on a shared server with uses IIS6 and ASP.NET2.0 (They advertise 3.5 but investigation on my part has proven this to be false).

I did some legwork to make my 3.5-sensitive ASP.NET apps compile on my hosting then discovered another problem: My apps are failing at 'File.Open()' calls due to no FileIOPermissions.

I've called Technical Support and they've advised me this permission is only available if I configure IIS6 to use .NET 1.1 only.  Am I out of line by thinking this is just not good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that should have been nutted out before starting to pay them, unless this disk access is a new requirement.

I can see it from their point of view. Every extra bit of power your apps have gives you more ability to shoot yourself (and more importantly, them) in the foot.

But I don't know why they'd allow it for an earlier .NET version, that seems bizarre.

I would make it clear that this is a deal-breaker. They might recapitulate, or you may have to move elsewhere. Either way, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Fair enough.  I honestly didn't think to ask.  "Clear only if known syndrome" if you will.  I'll certainly do more homework before putting another provider on the payroll.

Comment: I'd ask, though. That tech support comment seems like claptrap to me. Either file access is dangerous or not, why would it be more so in a later .Net? If they accede to you, you don't have the hassle of moving.